# CMake: custom command to copy files matching a pattern and preserve directory structure

Tags: cmake

I have the following project layout:

```
project/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ main.cpp
╘═ my_lib/
   ├─ CMakeLists.txt
   ╞═ some_package1/
   │  ├── header.hpp
   │  └── impl.cpp
   ╘═ some_package2/
      ├── header.hpp
      └── impl.cpp
```

`my_lib` is added as a subdirectory by the `CMakeLists.txt` from `project`.
What I would like to have is a target in `my_lib` `CMakeLists.txt` which, when built, executes a command that copies all headers in `my_lib` to a destination directory, while preserving directory structure. The destination directory would be defined by the `project` `CMakeLists.txt`.

Basically, if I could somehow get `add_custom_command` to do this:

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib DESTINATION ${COPY_DEST_DIR} FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.hpp")
```

I would be extremely happy. But I haven't found a way to do that. This is very similar to an install target, except I need it done before anything gets even compiled.

I tried doing the following:

```
set(MY_LIB_HEADER_FILES
    some_package1/header.hpp
    some_package2/header.hpp
)

add_custom_target(copy_headers)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET copy_headers
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${MY_LIB_HEADER_FILES}" ${COPY_DEST_DIR}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib
)
```

But that doesn't preserve directory structure, which in just this example case would lead to one header being overwritten by the other. I haven't been able to find a workaround to that.

The only solution I can imagine is a hack in which I loop over every file in `${MY_LIB_HEADER_FILES}`, remove whatever follows the last forward slash, create that directory, and then copy the file over to it. But that really isn't something I want to resort to and come to think of it, I'm not even sure how I'd go about it considering it must be done in an `add_custom_command` call.

Surely there is a solution, right?

Comment: Did you try `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directories` instead of `copy`?

Comment: I would end up copying source files along with headers, as `copy_directories` offers no option to match files whatsoever. However, as was suggested in an answer which is seemingly no longer here, I could then use `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` to find source files in the destination directory and delete them. This is far from ideal but for lack of a better solution that's probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: I hope you find a good solution. But you might also consider re-organizing your directory structure. I find it useful to have "external" header files (files which end users need to use the compiled code) in a separate directory from the source and internal header files. That makes it much easier to use something like `copy_directories` to install them.

Comment: @EricBackus that's actually sort of what I was trying to achieve. That may be personal but I'm not fond of the idea of manually maintaining a separate location for library headers (unless I misunderstood what you meant), hence why I want a script doing it automatically.  What this conundrum led me to, however, is to reorganize my whole code so that the "copy everything before anything is compiled"-part is no longer a requirement. Regardless, the accepted answer provides a nice way to do it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to achieve this is to write a "CMake script" file that will contain your `file(COPY ....)` command and to execute it within `add_custom_command`. In brief, your code snippet would look like this:

```
#create script file during configure phase...
file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cp.cmake
  "file(COPY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_lib DESTINATION ${COPY_DEST_DIR} FILES_MATCHING PATTERN *.hpp)\n"
)

#execute the script during the build phase...
add_custom_command(
  TARGET my_lib
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cp.cmake
)
```

`file(WRITE ....` statement will create a new cmake script file within the root build folder named `cp.cmake`.

Note 1:
The `$` preceding variables `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` and `COPY_DEST_DIR` are **not** escaped, meaning that the `cp.cmake` will contain their evaluated values.

Note 2:
It is assumed that your library creates a target named `my_lib` and `add_custom_command` is added as a `POST_BUILD` event for that target.

In the end, here is the cmake documentation about [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html), [file command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) and [running CMake in script mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you loads. 